# yarn install warning "xxx > xxx > xxx" has incorrect peer dependency "xxx"

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

When I run `yarn install`, the command line output is as follows:

> ```
> warning "@umijs/preset-react > @umijs/plugin-dva > dva@2.6.0-beta.22" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.4".
> warning "@umijs/preset-react > @umijs/plugin-dva > dva@2.6.0-beta.22" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.4".
> warning "@umijs/preset-react > @umijs/plugin-dva > dva-loading@3.0.22" has unmet peer dependency "dva-core@^1.1.0 | ^1.5.0-0 | ^1.6.0-0".
> warning "@umijs/preset-react > @umijs/plugin-locale > react-intl@3.12.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.3.0".
> warning "@umijs/preset-react > @umijs/plugin-request > @ahooksjs/use-request@2.8.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.6".
> ```

My yarn version is 1.22.10.

Answer (score 0):

This mean's there is some error with the dependencies warned about, but this shouldn't stop yarn from moving forward, to fix this you would have to upgrade yarn, running the command below you upgrade yarn:

`yarn upgrade --latest`

When yarn is fully updated, reinstall the dependencies using the same `yarn install`.

Comment: I didn't find `yarn add latest-version` in the document. Is its function to upgrade `yarn` to the latest version?

Comment: Yes, if that didn't work using `yarn upgrade --latest` should.

Comment: Sorry neither of these two solutions solved the problem.

Comment: Is a CodeSandbox demo available? That would help in resolving this.